# PhantomJS 2.0 + PHPUnit + Selenium: anyone got it working?

Tags: selenium

I'd like to replace Firefox with PhantomJS for our PHPUnit-run Selenium tests. However, I haven't got a clue how to start. When we're using Firefox, something like this is in our code:

```
$this->setBrowser("firefox");
$this->setFirefoxBinary("/path/to/firefox");
```

However, Phantom should probably be started as another service and when I run this command as suggested on the [Ghostdriver homepage](https://github.com/detro/ghostdriver):

```
 phantomjs --webdriver=8080 --webdriver-selenium-grid-hub=http://127.0.0.1:4444
```

It just fails with

```
[INFO  - 2015-03-06T14:55:02.431Z] GhostDriver - Main - running on port 8080
[INFO  - 2015-03-06T14:55:02.438Z] GhostDriver - Main - registering to Selenium HUB 'http://127.0.0.1:4444' version:  using '127.0.0.1:8080' with org.openqa.grid.selenium.proxy.DefaultRemoteProxy as remote proxy.
[ERROR - 2015-03-06T14:55:02.462Z] GhostDriver - main.fail - {"line":96,"sourceURL":"","stack":"\tat \n\tat global code (:/ghostdriver/main.js:78:37)"}

  :262 in error
```

I haven't been able to find any tutorials or anything for the new version 2.0, has anyone got it working?

Answer (score 3):

Or there's a third alternative to what Vangelisz suggested.

Here's a dirty & quick way to fix the issue.

- Fire up your favorite hex editor and edit/view the phantomjs executable:

  `$ dhex /usr/bin/phantomjs`
- For ghostdriver is written in javascript and embedded in the phantomjs distribution as plain-text, look for the line that's causing the bug:
  [image]
- Remove the line by filling up it with `0x20` (space) values. The line that you need to find and fill with ascii space characters is this: 
  `platform: ghostdriver.system.os.name + '-' + ghostdriver.system.os.version + '-' + ghostdriver.system.os.architecture,`
  [image]
- And then run as usual.

  `$ phantomjs --webdriver=8080 --webdriver-selenium-grid-hub=http://127.0.0.1:4444`

  > [INFO  - 2015-06-09T16:30:16.636Z] GhostDriver - Main - running on port 8080
  >   [INFO  - 2015-06-09T16:30:16.636Z] GhostDriver - Main - registering to Selenium HUB '' version:  using '127.0.0.1:8080' with org.openqa.grid.selenium.proxy.DefaultRemoteProxy as remote proxy.
  >   [INFO  - 2015-06-09T16:30:16.689Z] HUB Register - register - Registered with grid hub:  (ok)

Follow up: https://gist.github.com/neuro-sys/41e368839a9b20dafb34

Answer (score 2):

This was a bug in the latest version: https://github.com/detro/ghostdriver/issues/394

Either you build your own executable with the hint provided, or wait for the fix (or use an earlier build).